# Why can't copy html5 video (from camera) to canvas in Google Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm developing a feature in a web app, which enables the user to take a photo with whatever camera is attached to the device. This is mostly to be used in an Android v4.0+ phone with Google Chrome v28+.

In both desktop and phone I can setup a video tag to properly display video form the device's camera using `getUserMedia` and `createObjectURL`. My problem is that when I try to *draw* a snapshot from the video element nothing gets copied to the canvas:

```
var oVideo = jQuery('#myVideo');
var oCanvas = jQuery('#myCanvas');
var oContexto = oCanvas[0].getContext("2d");
var nAncho = oVideo.width();
var nAlto = oVideo.height();

//resizes the canvas: css
oCanvas.width(nAncho);
oCanvas.height(nAlto);
//resizes the canvas: image resolution
oCanvas[0].width = nAncho;
oCanvas[0].height = nAlto;

oContexto.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
oContexto.drawImage(oVideo[0], 0, 0, nAncho, nAlto);
oContexto.fillRect(80, 80, 40, 40);
```

I added the two `fillRect` just to be sure that the code was being executed. The result is that the two black rectangles are being drawn but the snapshot is not.

The problem only occurs in Google Chrome v28 for Android, but works properly in Google Chrome 28 (and Firefox 22) for windows.

Is it a Google Chrome's bug (I couldn't find it in http://code.google.com/p/chromium/)? Is there a work around? Or I'm simply doing some thing wrong?

I'll appreciate any insight to help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still persists on pre-Lollipop devices (<5). Have you been able to fix it / find a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a workaround. The feature was put on stand by, and I hadn't take care of the issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of not being able to draw video frames to a canvas is mentioned in the following issues:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174642
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181037

Both suggest the problem has been solved, but as I'm not familiar with the development process I don't know if this means it will work on our phones any time soon.

Edit: I just tried this in Chrome Beta and it works fine.